# creating foreign key with laravel gives error: Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, laravel, migration

I want to add two tables, a product table and a category table. Then I want to link a category id from the product table to the primary key from the category table. Here is my code:

The code to create my products table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->bigIncrements('id');
      $table->string('title');
      $table->string('imgpath');
      $table->text('description');
      $table->integer('price');
      $table->integer('hotItemNumber')->nullable();
      $table->timestamps();
      $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

The code to create my categories table:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('categroyName');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

The code to create my foreign key (in a seperate migrations file):

```
public function up()
{
  Schema::table('products', function($table) {
    $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
  });
}
```

I expected to create a foreign key but it gives an error.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
>   (SQL: alter table `products` add constraint
>   `products_categoryid_foreign` foreign key (`categoryid`) references
>   `categories` (`id`))

Comment: Have you tried to move `Schema::table('products', function($table) {/**/});` into another, separate migration?

Comment: @Tarasovych Yes I tried it and it gives the same error

Comment: What's your Laravel version?

Comment: it should be `$table->integer('categoryid')->unsigned()->index();`

Comment: @Tarasovych it's v5.8.17

Comment: What about `$table->unsignedBigInteger('categoryid');`?

Comment: If you are creating categories table first then, `products` table does not exists at the time of adding `categoryid` column to it and if you are creating `products` table first check if you are able to add the new column correctly to it from second migration, then only you can index right?

Comment: @SalmanZafar then it still gives the same error

Comment: @RobinSel `categoryid` it should be `category_id`

Comment: @SalmanZafar I edited it but still gives the same error

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu I edited my question and I create first all tables and after it I create the foreign key but still gives the same error

Comment: @Tarasovych If I use unsignedBigIntegere it's working thanks for the answer

Comment: If you don't mind, I'll add an answer for the question

Comment: Is the error is only this much what you have posted, or there is something more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your `products` table `id` has `int` datatype,`categoryid` should have the same data type.

Use `$table->unsignedBigInteger('categoryid');` instead.

[Reference](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=4095):

> a foreign key column must have the same data type + the same length +
>   the same scale as the corresponding referenced column

Answer (score 1):

in your new migration try changing the type like below

```
public function up()
{
  Schema::table('products', function($table) {
    $table->bigInteger('category_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
  });
}
```

because in your `categories` table the id is of type `bigIncrements`